# Evaluate the model during training affects its performance PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

In `PyTorch`, I want to evaluate my model on the validation set every `eval_step` during training, and I wrote code like this:

```py
def tune(model, loader_train, loader_dev, optimizer, epochs, eval_step):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for step,x in enumerate(loader_train):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss = model(x)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            
            if step % eval_step == 0:
                model.eval()
                test(model, loader_dev)
                model.train()
```

When `eval_step = int(len(loader_train)/2)` and `eval_step = int(len(loader_train)/8)`, they lead to quite different metric result **after training through one whole epoch** (which means the second output for the former differs the eighth output for the latter).

Could anyone explain why?

---

The length of `loader_train` is 20000 (it depends on batch size), and here is my testing script:

```py
def test(model, loader_dev):
    preds = []
    labels = []
    for step,x in enumerate(loader_dev):
        preds.append(model(x).view(-1))
        labels.apend(x['label'].view(-1))

    metric = cal_metric(preds, labels)
    logger.info(metric)
```

Comment: You haven't given a lot: what is the length of `loader_train`? Did you check the step numbers corresponded in both experiments? How is `test` implemented?

Comment: If your model is oscillating a lot, then you might want to consider lowering the learning rate (or use a LR scheduler). But as @Ivan points out, more details are required to properly analyze the issue.

Comment: @Ivan, @akshayk07, I added my test scripts (simplified) and I guarantee there is nothing wrong in my `cal_metric` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably set 'shffule=True' in your dataloader. Even though you fix 'random seed', dataloader in torch will generate different results if you use another dataloader while using current dataloader. In the scenario you describe, it may cause your model get data input in different order and then result in different metric result.

Comment: Even with `shuffle=True`, and a fixed seed you **will** get the same random sequences.

Comment: If training set use 'shuffle=true' and validation set use 'shuffle=False', then result of using 'training set->validation set->training set->validation set' will be different from result of 'training set->training set->validation set'.