# Why are model parameters different when `evaluate_during_training` is set to True and False?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, python-3.7, pytorch-dataloader

Why set `evaluate_during_training` True and False results in different model parameters during training?

During the first training process of my network, I set `evaluate_during_training` to `True` and set the `val_yaml` to the validation path, which will evaluate model on `validation set`. During the second training process of my network, I set `evaluate_during_training` to `False`. But after one epoch, I check the `model.bin` saved in these 2 process respectively, and find some of the model parameters are different.
This is the code of `training`:

```
for iteration, (img_keys, batch, meta_data) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        iteration += 1
        data_time = time.time() - end
        batch = tuple(t.to(args.device) for t in batch)
        model.train()
        # img_feats (B, #F, C, W, H)

        ...

        if args.deepspeed_fp16:  # True
            # deepspeed does not autocast inputs
            inputs = fp32_to_fp16(inputs)

        if args.mixed_precision_method == "fairscale":
            with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=True):
                outputs = model(**inputs)
        else:
            outputs = model(**inputs)
        loss, logits = outputs[:2]

        ...

        batch_score = compute_score_with_logits(logits, masked_ids)
        batch_acc = torch.sum(batch_score.float()) / torch.sum(inputs['masked_pos'])
        running_loss(loss.item())
        running_batch_acc(batch_acc.item())
        
        # backward pass
        backward_now = iteration % args.gradient_accumulation_steps == 0
        if args.mixed_precision_method == "deepspeed": # True
            model.backward(loss)
        elif args.mixed_precision_method == "fairscale":
            scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        else:
            # apex
            with amp.scale_loss(loss, optimizer, delay_unscale=not backward_now) as scaled_loss:
                scaled_loss.backward()
        if backward_now:
            global_step += 1

            ...

            if args.max_grad_norm != -1:
                grad_norm = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(
                    amp.master_params(optimizer), args.max_grad_norm)
            ...

            if args.mixed_precision_method == "deepspeed":
                model.step()
            restorer.step()
        
        if backward_now:
            if global_step % args.logging_steps == 0 or global_step == max_global_step:

                ...

                TB_LOGGER.add_scalar("train/speed", speed, global_step)
                log_start = time.time()


            if (args.save_steps > 0 and global_step % args.save_steps == 0) or global_step == max_global_step or global_step == 1:
                epoch = global_step // global_iters_per_epoch
                
                checkpoint_dir = op.join(args.output_dir, 'checkpoint-{}-{}'.format(
                    epoch, global_step))
                if get_world_size() > 1:
                    dist.barrier()
                # save model before eval
                training_saver.save_model(
                    checkpoint_dir, global_step, model, optimizer)
                if get_world_size() > 1:
                    dist.barrier()    
                # eval from here 
                if args.evaluate_during_training:
                    # the code of function evaluate will be following
                    evaluate_file = evaluate(args, val_dataloader, model, tokenizer, checkpoint_dir)
                    if get_world_size() > 1:
                        dist.barrier()
                    if is_main_process():
                        with open(evaluate_file, 'r') as f:
                            res = json.load(f)
                        val_log = {f'valid/{k}': v for k,v in res.items()}
                        TB_LOGGER.log_scalar_dict(val_log)
                        aml_run.log(name='CIDEr', value=float(res['CIDEr']))
                        
                        best_score = max(best_score, res['CIDEr'])   
                        res['epoch'] = epoch
                        res['iteration'] = iteration
                        res['best_CIDEr'] = best_score
                        eval_log.append(res)
                        with open(op.join(args.output_dir, args.val_yaml.replace('/','_')+'eval_logs.json'), 'w') as f:
                            json.dump(eval_log, f)
                    if get_world_size() > 1:
                        dist.barrier()
```

This is the code of `evaluate`:

```
def evaluate(args, val_dataloader, model, tokenizer, output_dir):
    predict_file = get_predict_file(output_dir, args,
            val_dataloader.dataset.yaml_file)
    test(args, val_dataloader, model, tokenizer, predict_file)
    # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    if get_world_size() > 1:
        dist.barrier()
    evaluate_file = get_evaluate_file(predict_file)
    if is_main_process():
        caption_file = val_dataloader.dataset.get_caption_file_in_coco_format()
        data = val_dataloader.dataset.yaml_file.split('/')[-2]
        result = evaluate_on_coco_caption(predict_file, caption_file, outfile=evaluate_file)
        logger.info(f'evaluation result: {str(result)}')
        logger.info(f'evaluation result saved to {evaluate_file}')
    if get_world_size() > 1:
        dist.barrier()
    return evaluate_file
```

This is the code of `test` called by `evaluate`:

```
def test(args, test_dataloader, model, tokenizer, predict_file):
    world_size = get_world_size()
    if world_size == 1:
        cache_file = predict_file
    else:
        # local_rank would not work for cross-node distributed training
        cache_file = op.splitext(predict_file)[0] + '_{}_{}'.format(get_rank(),
                world_size) + op.splitext(predict_file)[1]

    model.eval()
    # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    def gen_rows():
        time_meter = 0
        # restore existing results for long running inference tasks
        exist_key2pred = {}
        tmp_file = cache_file + '.tmp.copy'
        
        ...

        with torch.no_grad():
            for step, (img_keys, batch, meta_data) in tqdm(enumerate(test_dataloader)):
                # torch.cuda.empty_cache()
                is_exist = True
                for k in img_keys:
                    ...

                if is_exist:
                    ...
                batch = tuple(t.to(args.device) for t in batch)
                inputs = {...
                }
                
                if args.deepspeed_fp16:
                    # deepspeed does not auto cast inputs.
                    inputs = fp32_to_fp16(inputs)

                if args.mixed_precision_method == "fairscale":
                    with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=True):
                        outputs = model(**inputs)
                else:
                    outputs = model(**inputs)
                time_meter += time.time() - tic
                all_caps = outputs[0]  # batch_size * num_keep_best * max_len
                all_confs = torch.exp(outputs[1])

                for img_key, caps, confs in zip(img_keys, all_caps, all_confs):
                    res = []
                    for cap, conf in zip(caps, confs):
                        cap = tokenizer.decode(cap.tolist(), skip_special_tokens=True)
                        res.append({'caption': cap, 'conf': conf.item()})
                    if isinstance(img_key, torch.Tensor):
                        img_key = img_key.item()
                    yield img_key, json.dumps(res)

        logger.info(f"Inference model computing time: {(time_meter / (step+1))} seconds per batch")
    
    # call the function above
    tsv_writer(gen_rows(), cache_file)
    if world_size > 1:
        dist.barrier()
    if world_size > 1 and is_main_process():
        ...
```

I show very complete code, because I am afraid that some omitted parts will be the cause of the phenomenon described in the question. By the way, the `train_dataloader` and `val_dataloader` are **2** variables generated by the same function:

```
train_dataloader = make_data_loader(args, args.train_yaml, tokenizer, args.distributed, is_train=True, num_gpus=args.num_gpu)

val_dataloader = make_data_loader(args, args.val_yaml, tokenizer, args.distributed, is_train=False, num_gpus=args.num_gpu)
```

This is the function of `make_data_loader`:

```
def make_data_loader(args, yaml_file, tokenizer, is_distributed=True,
        is_train=True, start_iter=0, num_gpus=8):

    dataset = build_dataset(args, yaml_file, tokenizer, is_train=is_train)
    if is_train==True:
        shuffle = True
        images_per_gpu = args.per_gpu_train_batch_size
        images_per_batch = images_per_gpu * get_world_size()
        iters_per_batch = len(dataset) // images_per_batch
        num_iters = iters_per_batch * args.num_train_epochs
    else:
        shuffle = False
        images_per_gpu = args.per_gpu_eval_batch_size
        num_iters = None
        start_iter = 0

    random_seed = args.seed
    sampler = make_data_sampler(
        dataset, shuffle, is_distributed, limited_samples=limited_samples,
        random_seed=random_seed)
    batch_sampler = make_batch_data_sampler(
        sampler, images_per_gpu, num_iters, start_iter
    )
    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset, num_workers=args.num_workers, batch_sampler=batch_sampler,
        pin_memory=True, worker_init_fn=init_seeds,
    )
    return data_loader
```

I use the `deepspeed` mixed precision method. During training, I set the `shuffle = True` and during evaluate I set `shuffle = False`. The seed is always fixed.

I set `model.eval()` and `with torch.no_grad():` during evaluation, and I also compare the model parameters before and after the `if args.evaluate_during_training:` code block in training loop, they are the same. So I guess the evaluation process does not change the parameters as expected. But why after one full epoch, the parameters of `evaluate_during_training` true and false are different?

The problem may have some relationship with [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68736827/evaluate-the-model-during-training-affects-its-performance-pytorch) but I did not get ananswer from that so ask a new question. This problem is driving me crazy and I sincerely hope someone could give me some instruction. Thank you in advance!